# How do I fix the following to make it sequential?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I was wondering if you could help with the following. I have just started using VBA but I am having an issue with applying the following formula to the dataset.

```
Selection.Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX('beach'!B:B,MATCH(F19,'beach'!$G:$G,0)),0)"
```

F19 is a set cell, however, I need F19 to be sequential, as in that when the calculation is completed in cell `M20` rather than `M19`, the formula is updated to calculate using `F20`.

Also, following on from that how do I edit the above formula to allow the macros to be applied to all cells in a Column?

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
Sub poiuyt()
    Range("M19:M20").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX('beach'!B:B,MATCH(F19,'beach'!$G:$G,0)),0)"
End Sub
```

will auto-adjust the **F** index:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `R1C1` style.

Say you want that formula to apply in range `M19:M20` with your `F19` reference updating to each row:

```
Range("M19:M20").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFNA(INDEX(beach!C[-11],MATCH(RC[-7],beach!C7,0)),0)"
```